# Postgis Query ST_Intersects with GeoJSON (jsonb)

Tags: postgresql, casting, postgis, jsonb

Given a PostgreSQL 9.4 jsonb column 'location' with content like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
  {
    "properties": {},
    "geom": "01030000000100000004000000000000000000244000000000000049400000000000002840000000000000494000000000000026400000000000004A4000000000000024400000000000004940",
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[10,50],[12,50],[11,52],[10,50]]]}             
  },
  {..},
  {..}
]}
```

To retrieve the feature key 'geom' I use this query:

```
SELECT geom
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(t.location -> 'features') -> 'geom' AS geom
  FROM my_object t) AS g
WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Works. But now I would like to do a Postgis `ST_Intersects` query like this:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(g.geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11 51)'))
FROM (
  SELECT t.iid, (jsonb_array_elements(t.location -> 'features') -> 'geom') AS geom
  FROM my_object t) AS g;
```

Doesn't work because g.geom is delivered as `jsonb`: `function st_intersects(jsonb, geometry) does not exist`. I tried casting to `text`, the error then is `function st_intersects(text, geometry) is not unique`. How I have to deal with `jsonb` results as input for Postgis functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the function `jsonb_array_elements()` returns a set so you should it as a [table function in a `FROM` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS). Secondly, you should get the text representation of the `jsonb` field with the `->>` operator and then cast that to `geometry` which you then use in a PostGIS function.

To retrieve the geometries that are not `NULL`:

```
SELECT f.value ->> 'geom' AS geom
FROM my_object t
JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.location -> 'features') f ON true
WHERE f.value -> 'geom' IS NOT NULL;
```

To do the intersect:

```
SELECT t.iid, ST_Intersects((f.value->>'geom')::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11 51)'))
FROM my_object t
JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.location -> 'features') f ON true;
```

You probably want to add some `properties` to the select list such that you can distinguish between multiple geometries for each row from your table.

Comment: Perfect,thanks! One minor question: it seems it works without LATERAL key word the same way  ..?

Comment: With a table function the keyword `LATERAL` is indeed optional, as is also described in the documentation I refer to. I included it here for "educational purposes".

Answer (score 1):

To create a postgis geometry type from the geojson you can use the function [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html)

For example:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}');
```

Comment: Yes, I know this option. But I would like to use the pre-calculated 'geom' as input, not the GeoJSON object. It was my hope to avoid this extra conversion (geomfromgeojson) to make the query faster.

Comment: rigth. Then you can try with ST_GeomFromWKB. But, if you want to avoid the extra conversion i think that i will be better, create a new geometry column in your table.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work: function st_geomfromwkb(jsonb) does not exist